# Access to the remote machine via terminal

Tags: terminal, centos, tty

How can I read the files and folders of a remote machine which I can ping?

```
PING 172.17.0.4 (172.17.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.114 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.122 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.120 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.124 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.4: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.150 ms
^C
--- 172.17.0.4 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5177ms
```

Comment: If you have an account there, `ssh your-username@172.17.0.4`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to login the remote machine? Is so, do ssh

*ssh username@remotemachinename/ip*

Comment: not login, i want just to get access to the files of the remote mashine using terminal

Comment: @VPaskar SSH is the first step, look up sftp, that's one way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

One way to mount a remote server locally is to set up NFS (the Network File System).

> NFS mounts work to share a directory between several servers. This has
>   the advantage of saving disk space, as the home directory is only kept
>   on one server, and others can connect to it over the network. When
>   setting up mounts, NFS is most effective for permanent fixtures that
>   should always be accessible.

Instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-centos-6

You'll need to actually have administrator access on the master box to set it up.